# How to timestamp two streams and synchronize them at receiver?

Tags: c#, audio, video, synchronization, directshow

I have two streams of data, one with audio data,the other with video data.
The sound i record with `DirectSound` is put in a buffer of 100ms length and a `DirectShow` `ISampleGrabbe` witch grabs frame for me at 30 frames per second(one frame at each 33,33 ms).

What `TimeStamping` means? Should I attach to the video/audio a `DateTime` field and verify at receiving which audio packet have the same `TimeStamp` with the video frame?

I know this is a really hard subject, but can you please give me an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means each video/audio element has a time offset that says when it must be played in relation to when the video/audio was started. So the receiving end will order received elements by their timestamp and play them in order, also it will wait when video or audio elements are missing.

You should not add a DateTime attribute to every element. Instead the video/audio header should indicate at what framerate or frequency the media must be played and therefore how much elements it will receive every second. So a simple autonumber would do. It's the players responsibility to order the received elements and check if the point to where it has received all elements is far enough in the future that it can keep playing.

Comment: Thank you!It is more clear for me now.To a frame(image) packet i should put the number(1-30) of the frame and to the sound packet i should put 1-10?Because in a second i receive ten 10 packet of 100 ms sound.Sound will arrive more quickly than image,should i wait for the image header and then play both?

Comment: Yes, wait for both. The numbers i would do differens, seperating the numbers based on which second they are played would only complicate things. If you have 30 fps you can play over 20k hours using only integers, should be enough. You should buffer your images and sound and find the point at which you have all sound and image elements. If that point is far enough (maybe 1 sec) ahead of current play time, play them both.